# Jenkins pipeline - Trigger a new build for a given job

Tags: docker, jenkins, pipeline

I have two Jenkins pipelines, named **A** and **B**. Both use the same docker container, named **C1**. The job **A** looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'c1'
        }
    }
    stages {
        ...
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                echo "always"
            }
        }
        success {
            script {
                echo "success"
            }
        }
        failure {
            script {
                echo "failure"
            }
        }
        unstable { 
            script {
                echo "unstable"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is in the job **B**. This, in the post action **always** calls the job **A**, like this:

```
build job: 'A/master', parameters: [ string(name: 'p1', value: params["p1"])  ]
```

The error occures by starting the job **A**, saying:

```
Error when executing success post condition:
hudson.AbortException: No item named A/master found
```

And also, by listing the parent folders, it is evident that there is no folder for job **A**.

How could I solve this problem?

KI

Comment: What type of pipeline is A? Have you multiple repositories in a project there?

Comment: Each job is a Jenkins pipeline defined within a Jenkinsfile and are stored in separated git repositories.

Comment: So you don't use the Bitbucket plugin or so? if so, when going into your job overview (not Blueocean) you see an URL like `<jenkinsBaseURL>/job/<project>/job/<repository>/job/<branch>` which means the full job name will be `<project>/<repository>/</branch>` e.g. `FOO/myrepo/master`. My guess here is, that the job name is just wrong.

Comment: I use the Gitea plugin to get the Jenkinsfile for each job. I checked again the name of it but the same error. If I start them separately, then it is OK.

Comment: Did you check the URL to see if the jobs name is correct? Idk Gitea, but I can see they separate the repositories by users, so I guess the correct job name is `<giteauser>/<repo>/<branch>`.

Comment: Yes, I checked it and it is correct.

Comment: Could run this in the script console (under Manage Jenkins):
`Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class).each {
 println(it.fullName)
};`

This will print all full jobs names, so you can check if the name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is the folder name in which these jobs are located. So, the name of the job is **test/A/master**.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I've read you're using the Gitea plugin to receive the repositories from your Gitea instance. Gitea repositories are organized per user/organization like Github does.

Once you've added a Gitea project (user/organization) via the Jenkins plugin the full name of one of the jobs will be:

```
<user_or_orga>/<repository_name>/<branch>
```

For example for the user name "crash", where the repository "stackoverflow" belongs to, it would be (for the master branch):

```
crash/stackoverflow/master
```

To get a list of all items including all **full** job names you can run this in the script console (under Manage Jenkins):

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(AbstractItem.class).each {      
    println(it.fullName)
};
```

P.S. for the Bitbucket plugin and others it's the same rule.